# I am Unable to start OpenSSH with Windows PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, ssh

**Problem:** Unable to issue command `Start-Service sshd` in Windows PowerShell 7.2.6.

**Expected Results:** OpenSSH Server Starts.

**Actual Results:** `Start-Service: Cannot find any service with service name 'sshd'.`.

**Investigation:** Above error clearing indicates OpenSSH Server is not installed.

**Root Problem:** Issuing `Add-WindowsCapability -Online -Name OpenSSH.Server~~~0.0.1.0` does not appear to install OpenSSH server.

*Verifying OpenSSH Server is not installing via above command:*

```
PowerShell 7.2.6

PS > Get-WindowsCapability -Online | Where-Object Name -like 'OpenSSH*'

Name  : OpenSSH.Client~~~~0.0.1.0
State : Installed

Name  : OpenSSH.Server~~~~0.0.1.0
State : NotPresent

PS > Add-WindowsCapability -Online -Name OpenSSH.Server~~~0.0.1.0

Path          :
Online        : True
RestartNeeded : False

PS > Get-WindowsCapability -Online | Where-Object Name -like 'OpenSSH*'

Name  : OpenSSH.Client~~~~0.0.1.0
State : Installed

Name  : OpenSSH.Server~~~~0.0.1.0
State : NotPresent
```

Am I missing anything with trying to installing OpenSSH Server on Windows 10?

**Attempted:** Uninstall and Reinstall OpenSSH.Server.

```
PowerShell 7.2.6

PS > Remove-WindowsCapability -Online -Name OpenSSH.Server~~~~0.0.1.0

Path          :
Online        : True
RestartNeeded : False

PS > Add-WindowsCapability -Online -Name OpenSSH.Server~~~0.0.1.0

Path          :
Online        : True
RestartNeeded : False

PS > Get-WindowsCapability -Online | Where-Object Name -like 'OpenSSH*'

Name  : OpenSSH.Client~~~~0.0.1.0
State : Installed

Name  : OpenSSH.Server~~~~0.0.1.0
State : NotPresent
```

Via [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1688019/cant-install-open-ssh-server-in-windows-10) although different they seem to be able to install it. (Accepted is a good alternative if I cant get this working, however I would prefer following either [Win32-OpenSSH GitHub](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH) or the [Official Microsoft Resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse?tabs=powershell))

```
PowerShell 7.2.6

PS > Get-WindowsCapability -Online -Name OpenSSH.Server~~~0.0.1.0

Name         :
State        : NotPresent
DisplayName  :
Description  :
DownloadSize : 0
InstallSize  : 0

PS > Get-WindowsCapability -Online | Where-Object Name -like 'OpenSSH*'

Name  : OpenSSH.Client~~~~0.0.1.0
State : Installed

Name  : OpenSSH.Server~~~~0.0.1.0
State : NotPresent

PS > Add-WindowsCapability -Online -Name OpenSSH.Server*

Path          :
Online        : True
RestartNeeded : False

PS > Get-WindowsCapability -Online | Where-Object Name -like 'OpenSSH*'

Name  : OpenSSH.Client~~~~0.0.1.0
State : Installed

Name  : OpenSSH.Server~~~~0.0.1.0
State : NotPresent
```

[Similar Issue](https://superuser.com/questions/1341703/win10-openssh-failed-to-install-sshd-service?rq=1), however I do not have Cygwin Installed.

**Alternative:** Install via GUI or via Git clone. (I would like to use PS).

Additional Info:

```
PowerShell 7.2.6

PS > $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      7.2.6
PSEdition                      Core
GitCommitId                    7.2.6
OS                             Microsoft Windows 10.0.19044
Platform                       Win32NT
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0…}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
WSManStackVersion              3.0

>winver.exe

Version 21H2
OS Build 19044.1889
```

**Source:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse?tabs=powershell

Comment: As a sidenote, you don't have to pipe to `Where-Object` to filter. There's a `-Name` parameter that accepts wildcards: `Get-WindowsCapability -Online -Name open*`. Any difference using: `Get-WindowsCapability -Online -Name open* | Add-WindowsCapability -Online` instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per Abraham Zinalas Comment.

**Solution**

```
PS > Get-WindowsCapability -Online -Name open* | Add-WindowsCapability -Online

Path          :
Online        : True
RestartNeeded : False

Path          :
Online        : True
RestartNeeded : False


PS > Get-WindowsCapability -Online -Name open*

Name         : OpenSSH.Client~~~~0.0.1.0
State        : Installed
DisplayName  : OpenSSH Client
Description  : OpenSSH-based secure shell (SSH) client, for secure key management and access to
               remote machines.
DownloadSize : 1314377
InstallSize  : 10602592

Name         : OpenSSH.Server~~~~0.0.1.0
State        : Installed
DisplayName  : OpenSSH Server
Description  : OpenSSH-based secure shell (SSH) server, for secure key management and access from
               remote machines.
DownloadSize : 1290075
InstallSize  : 9894430

PS > Start-Service sshd
PS >
```

sshd successfully started!

Comment: Seems like it was missing something running `Add-WindowsCapability -Online -Name OpenSSH.Server~~~0.0.1.0` by itself, so when you ran `Get-WindowsCapability -Online -Name open*serve* | Add-WindowsCapability -Online` it probably bound those non-expected arguments to it. Glad it worked!

Comment: I'm surmising the same something wasn't all there! Thank you so much again for the help!